# better way pass data to API helper class

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have an api helper class where I'm getting notification data. Everything is working fine but I want to know the better way to pass the data to that helper class.

So I want know that How can pass the id to the helper class,

API helper class,

```
class NotificationStore = _NotificationStore with _$NotificationStore;

abstract class _NotificationStore with Store {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  _NotificationStore({String id}) { //<<<<<<<< id which I want
    foreGroundMessage();
    fetchToken(id);
  }

  @observable
  ObservableList<Notification> notifications = ObservableList<Notification>();

  Future<String> fetchToken(String id) async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) checkIOSPermission();
    var token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(id);
    return token;
  }

}
```

how I'm passing the **id** from widget,

```
class _NotificationTabState extends State<NotificationTab> {
  NotificationStore notificationStore;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false);//<<<<< getting id from provider
    notificationStore = NotificationStore(id: user.id); //<<<<<< passing the id
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        enableBackIcon: false,
        title: AppStrings.notifications,
      ),
      body: GradientBackground(...)
```

so I want make this widget stateless so is there any way to do it because I just made this widget stateful because I can access the provider in the `initState()`

Comment: In a `StatefullWidget` the `initState()` method called once and never call again during the  lifecycle of the widget. so in this case you passing your value from `initState()` If you migrated from `stateFull` to `stateless` you can pass your data from `build()` method because in `statelessWidget` the `build()` method called once .

Comment: @SaifulIslam I need to pass the `id` while initialising the `notificationStore` so how will I do that?

Comment: see the answer and let me know if you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

In your `statelessWidget`

put those line inside your `build()` method

```
final user = Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false);
notificationStore = NotificationStore(id: user.id);
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false);
    notificationStore = NotificationStore(id: user.id); 

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        enableBackIcon: false,
        title: AppStrings.notifications,
      ),
      body: GradientBackground(...)
```

Comment: but then I have to make `notificationStore` final otherwise I will get the warning from `linter`